# Power BI Odata Source Change Dynamically

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I have a Power BI task, and the scenario is as follows: I am working with a SharePoint application that manages projects, and each project has its subsite. My goal is to access all the lists of each subsite in Power BI. Currently, I can retrieve the list of a specific subsite using this URL: 'http://abc2019/pwa/Project1/_vti_bin/listdata.svc.' However, I need to dynamically replace the value of 'Project1' based on user selection. For instance, if the user chooses 'Project2' in the SharePoint application, I should be able to replace the value from 'Project1' with 'Project2' and fetch all the lists from the 'Project2' subsite.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How and where does the user choose "Project2".